# Programatically updating content in child div of Bootstrap modal-body div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my Bootstrap modal window - pretty rudimentary.

```
<div id="modal_test_form" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 >Hello
      </div>
      <div id="tbody" class="modal-body">
        <div id="tbody_part1">
           Change me! Change me!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <h3>Goodbye</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the modal window has been displayed, I'd like to update the contents of `div id="tbody_part1"`.  How do I do this using jquery?

```
$('#tbody_part1').html("new content!");
```

doesn't work.

Thanks!

Mmiz

Comment: what do you mean by *doesn't work* ? Please elaborate. What errors do you see in the console.

Comment: Sorry - my apologies for the incompleteness. When I display the window and try to write to `tbody_part1` nothing shows up in the window. Additionally, when I look at the HTML being displayed, the child div `tbody_part1` doesn't even show up. Just the  modal-body div `tbody`. Also, no errors in the console.

Comment: Your `<h2>` tag is unclosed - is that only in your example here or might that be your difficulty?

Comment: The code is working in Fiddle, that's not the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/c0mm0n/38frr4x4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to trigger the update after the modal has been loaded. I can't tell from the code you posted if you are doing an ajax load but here it is:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var $modal = $('#modal_test_form');
        $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $modal.find('#tbody_part1').html("new content!");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```